# show Year symbol after year value in Jquery Ui calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ui-calendar

I am using following code to show the calendar

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
         selectMultiple: true,
         monthNames: [ "1月","2月","3月","4月","5月","6月",
                         "7月","8月","9月","10月","11月","12月" ],
        dayNamesMin: ['日','月','火','水','木','金','土'],
        showMonthAfterYear: true, //this is what you are looking for

        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            date = jQuery(this).datepicker("getDate");
            var rs = date.getDate();                               
        }
        });
```

Current Output [image]

I want  to add the Year symbol after year like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I got this with following code.**

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        yearSuffix: "Year", //this is what you are looking for
    }

    });
```